# React returning 1 object from array of objects

Tags: arrays, reactjs, return

I have an array of Objects and a search function.  The search function takes in a user name and passes it to the profile render component which finds the user name and returns their data.  My problem right now, is I am using a conditional if block to search the array and return results.  This causes any user profile past the [0] spot in the array to have additional

tags which cause extra spacing.

Is there a way I can just loop through the array and return only the 1 I want?  I'am assuming that I might need to make a varible that handles the 1 true return then only return that.

Here is what I have so far.

```
const renderUser = this.props.data.map( (obj, idx) => {
                    return ( 
                            this.props.name === obj.name ? 
                                <p key={idx}>
                                        Name: {obj.name} < br/>
                                        Email: {obj.email} <br />
                                        Flavor: {obj.flavor} <br />
                                        STR: {obj.str} <br />
                                        AGI: {obj.agi} <br />
                                        INT: {obj.int} <br />
                                        STA: {obj.sta} <br />
                                    </p>
                                 :
                                <p key={idx}> </p>                   
                    )
                });
```

I can clean it up a little by adding a var to handle the data, but this causes the each element in an array needs a key error.

```
const renOneUser = this.props.data.map(( obj, idx ) => {
                    let userData;

                            this.props.name === obj.name ? 
                             userData =  <p key={idx}>
                                        Name: {obj.name} < br/>
                                        Email: {obj.email} <br />
                                        Flavor: {obj.flavor} <br />
                                        STR: {obj.str} <br />
                                        AGI: {obj.agi} <br />
                                        INT: {obj.int} <br />
                                        STA: {obj.sta} <br />
                                    </p>
                                 :
                                <p key={idx}> </p>       

                    return (
                        <div>
                            {userData}
                        </div>
                    )        
                });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the `filter` function, to filter by a condition, and then pass the results through the `map` function:

```
this.props.data.filter(obj => {
      return this.props.name === obj.name;
    }).map((obj, idx) => {
        return (
            <p key={idx}>
                        Name: {obj.name} < br/>
                        Email: {obj.email} <br />
                        Flavor: {obj.flavor} <br />
                        STR: {obj.str} <br />
                        AGI: {obj.agi} <br />
                        INT: {obj.int} <br />
                        STA: {obj.sta} <br />
            </p>
        );
    });
```